# Entity Framework Code First fluent API setting field properties in a for loop

Tags: .net, entity-framework, code-first

I am using Entity Framework Code First to create a database table. My model class has ten decimal fields. Currently I am setting the field property like this in the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Envelopes>().Property(p => p.cell_1_1).HasPrecision(18, 2);
```

Since I have ten fields I am thinking of using a `for` loop to set this precision property such as the following code:

```
for( int i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Envelopes>()
                .Property(p => p.Equals("cell_1_"+i ))
                .HasPrecision(18, 2);
}
```

However the above code is giving a me a syntax error.

Is it possible to set the precision value like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you - using reflection to get all the properties of type `decimal` in your entity, then building an expression tree for the property access and finally using the property access lambda to set the precision to the desired values.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var properties = typeof(Envelopes).GetProperties()
                                      .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(decimal));

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var lambda = BuildLambda<Envelopes, decimal>(property);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Envelopes>()
                    .Property(lambda)
                    .HasPrecision(18, 2);
    }
}

static Expression<Func<T, U>> BuildLambda<T,U>(PropertyInfo property)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
    MemberExpression memberExpression = Expression.Property(param, property);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, U>>(memberExpression, param);
    return lambda;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, this code not compiling its giving error on this line `var lambda = BuildLambda<Type1, decimal>(property);`  error message not able resolve **Type1**. Do I need to use (import) some library?

Comment: Where can I learn how the BuildLambda method works line by line? This confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

model creation with some reflection

```
var entityTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == "Namespace.Enitites");
foreach (var type in entityTypes)
{
    foreach (var property in type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(decimal)))
    {
        var entityConfig = modelBuilder.GetType().GetMethod("Entity").MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(modelBuilder, null);
        var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "c");
        var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(param, property), true, new[] { param });

        var items = entityConfig.GetType().GetMethods().Where(p => p.Name == "Property" && p.ReturnType == typeof(DecimalPropertyConfiguration)).ToArray();
        if (items.Length <= 0)
            continue;

        MethodInfo methodInfo;
        if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            methodInfo = items[1];
        else
            methodInfo = items[0];

        var decimalConfig = methodInfo.Invoke(entityConfig, new[] { lambdaExpression }) as DecimalPropertyConfiguration;
        if (decimalConfig != null)
            decimalConfig.HasPrecision(19, 4);
    }
}
```

or

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<DecimalPropertyConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new DecimalPropertyConvention(19, 4));
```